# Trying to escape a string to use as a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following code, which I stole from another SO question,

```
$('#'+'^`test'.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\\\$&"))
```

which produces the following error.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #\\^\\`test(…)

I just have some IDs with crazy characters, like ^ and `, that I need jQuery to not choke on. I don't get why that error is happening, because if I manually add the slashes into the string like,

```
$('#'+'\\^\\`test')
```

then it works fine. What's wrong with the regex method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just have some IDs with crazy characters, like ^ and `, that I need jQuery to not choke on.

By far the simplest way to address that is with an attribute selector:

```
$('[id="' + theId + '"]').doSomething();
```

As long as `theId` doesn't contain backslashes or double quotes, no need for further escaping.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder how that works. I think I will go with using getElementById, but I suppose this is the most direct answer to my question.

Comment: @Moss: It's an [attribute value selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation). But yes, `getElementById` is a great approach (why didn't I mention it?!) when IDs can be "wild." `$(document.getElementById(theId)).doSomething();`

Comment: What mean is I don't understand how your solution works but my first attempt didn't. Something specific to jQuery?

Comment: @Moss: No, it's just the rules of [ID selectors in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors). The text following the `#` has to follow the rules for [CSS identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), but the text within an attribute value selector doesn't, it just has to not have the kind of quote you used after the `=`. (And the text you pass into `getElementById` can be anything.)

Answer (score 2):

Another work around is to use the vanilla `getElementById`, which doesn't parse the selector. That way you still have the efficiency of selecting by id:

```
let res = $(document.getElementById('^`test'));
```

Comment: Warning to lurkers: `let` is ES2015+, it won't work in some browsers in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 times the escape . Becouse first the replace/regex need the escape to write a escape. The next escape is need from jquery by $().

More clear syntax as the postet regex is:

```
"#^bla`".replace('^','\\\^').replace('`','\\\`');
```

will replace "#^bla`" to "#\\^bla\\`".

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #\\^\\`test(…)

If you want to use your regex you must also escape [ ] with \[  and \].

```
"+".replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this?

```
const $ID = function(selector){
    return $('[id="' + selector.match(/#?(\S+)/)[1] + '"]')
}
```

Then you can use it just like jquery

```
$ID('#^`div')
```